# A compile-time counter for distinct Type identifier

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am writing some template meta programming code. For some reasons, I want to make every object in my code has different type. The original code looks like this:

```
template<unsigned int index>
class Class1{

};

template<typename T1, typename T2, unsigned int index>
class Class2{
    std::tuple<T1*, T2*> v;
  public:
    Class2(T1* t1, T2* t2): v(std::tuple<T1*, T2*>(t1, t2)) {}
};

template<unsigned int index>
auto makeClass1() {
    return Class1<index>();
}

template<unsigned int index, typename T1, typename T2>
auto mul(T1& t1, T2& t2) {
    return Class2<T1, T2, index>(&t1, &t2);
}    

int main() {
    auto t1 = makeClass1<0>();  // Type of TT1 is Class1<0>
    auto t2 = makeClass1<1>();  // Type of TT2 is Class1<1>
    auto m1 = mul<0>(t1, t2);
    auto m2 = mul<1>(t1, t2); // Type of m2 is different from type of m1.
}
```

This code is work, but I wish my code is easy to use. So I want to ask is there any solution that can make the code look like this:

```
template<unsigned int index>
class Class1{

};

template<typename T1, typename T2, unsigned int index>
class Class2{
    std::tuple<T1*, T2*> v;
  public:
    Class2(T1* t1, T2* t2): v(std::tuple<T1*, T2*>(t1, t2)) {}
};

template<unsigned int index = IncreaseCounter<?>::value>
auto makeClass1() {
    return Class1<index>();
}

template<unsigned int index = IncreaseCounter<?>::value, typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator*(T1& t1, T2& t2) {
    return Class2<T1, T2, index>(&t1, &t2);
}

int main() {
    auto t1 = makeClass1();  // Type of TT1 is Class1<0>
    auto t2 = makeClass1();  // Type of TT2 is Class1<1>
    auto m1 = t1*t2
    auto m2 = t1*t2; // Type of m2 is different from type of m1.
}
```

Note: I think I need a compile-time counter. But except the macro solution:`__COUNTER__` and `__LINE__` , I can't find any other compile-time solution. The macro solution is ineffective to my code.

Except the compile-time counter, any other solution is ok.

Thank you for reading my question. Due to my poor english expression ability，please bear with me for the wrong sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++20, you might do:

```
template <typename = decltype([]{})>
class Class1{};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename = decltype([]{})>
class Class2{
    std::tuple<T1*, T2*> v;
  public:
    Class2(T1* t1, T2* t2): v(std::tuple<T1*, T2*>(t1, t2)) {}
};

template <typename T = decltype([]{})>
auto makeClass1() { return Class1<T>();}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T = decltype([]{})>
auto operator*(T1& t1, T2& t2) {
    return Class2<T1, T2, T>(&t1, &t2);
}

int main() {
    auto t1 = makeClass1();
    auto t2 = makeClass1(); // Type of t2 is different from type of t1.
    auto m1 = t1*t2;
    auto m2 = t1*t2; // Type of m2 is different from type of m1.

    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(t1), decltype(t2)>);
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(m1), decltype(m2)>);
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f712cc025a7a4d7).

Comment: How does this work? Does the compiler instantiate a new type each time you access the template?

Comment: And does the standard guarantee that `!std::is_same_v<decltype([]{}), decltype([]{})>` holds in all cases?

Comment: Each lambda has its own type, so yes. (and default template arguments are instantiated at call site).

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. Could you tell me the name of this feature(`[]{}`) in C++20? I want to know more detail of this feature.

Comment: @Dreamer That's just a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and is not C++20 specific. However lambdas in unevaluated context is a C++20 feature. `decltype([]{})` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's regard the core of your question:

```
    auto m1 = t1*t2;
    auto m2 = t1*t2; // Type of m2 is different from type of m1.
```

You have exactly the same expression (`t1*t2`) but you wish this expression to produce two different types!

Overall your idea of counting objects in compile time is loose. What would you expect in this case?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        auto m = t1*t2;
    }
```

Returning back to your code: you somehow need to introduce this compile-time index, like you do in `mul<index>`: either in `mul` or in the result type (explicit type instead of `auto` + appropriate conversion).

Comment: Even if token are exactly the same, we might have different return type, see my answer for example. For the loop, we might argue that it is not a distinct identifier.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. I never thought about this situation before， thanks for reminding . I think every loop will return a different type, but this object will be destructed after each loop, so  object like this is not my point.